# Regular Pentagon, Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Can someone help me to find the value of $x$? I wish I could share my attempted solution but I really couldn't develop something interesting to share. I know that the value of the internal angle are $108^°$, because the sum of the internal angles of a convex polygon is $S=180^°(n-2)$, and they are all the same, because the it's a regular polygon. But that's all I figured out.
[image]

Comment: Hint: the triangle formed by the right line you drew has one angle given as 30° and one angle is an angle of the pentagon. What can you say about the third one (the one on the bottom line of the pentagon)?

Comment: The angle you mentioned is 42º (180º-30º-108º), but how it can help?

Comment: Ah, sorry, maybe it doesn't tell you as much as I thought at first...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel: What is the source of this question? Such information can provide readers with a sense of the level of difficulty expected in a solution. ... FYI: A GeoGebra sketch suggests that the answer is $90^\circ$.

Comment: @Blue, it's a question from a national math olympiad in Brazil for high school students. The question is from the first phase of the test, so I guess it's not something very complex.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the figure below, where $ABCDE$ is a regular pentagon, $F \in BC$ and $G \in AB$ with $EG \cong FG$, and $\measuredangle BFG = 30^\circ$. Also, $G'$ is taken in such a way that $\triangle FGG'$ is equilateral.

[image]

1. Show that $\triangle BGG'$ is isosceles, with $\measuredangle BGG' = \measuredangle BG'G = 18^\circ$.
2. Use Exterior Angle Theorem on $\triangle BGG'$, plus the fact that $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles, to show that $E$, $B$, and $G'$ are aligned.
3. Observing that $\triangle EGG'$ is isosceles, prove that $$\boxed{\measuredangle DEG = 90^\circ}.$$